# Log every time a cookie is created in javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox, cookies

I will like to create a kind of proxy that logs every time a cookie is created using javascript. But I don't know if it could be created overriding the prototype or how to do it in the best way.

For example, considering this code in a website:

```js
document.cookie = "test=myvalue;domain=test";
```

I will like to log in the console the Name and value of the created cookie. But I will not like to check it using the document.cookie to return all cookies and print the name and value, I want to do it in a dynamic way.

May it be possible to do it with the prototype?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I will explain better. I'm doing a extension to log every time a cookie is created via javascript using 'document.cookie=...' (Not via HTTP headers with set-cookie). The idea is to know the exact javascript file and line that created a determined cookie as well as the name and value of the created cookie. Consider for example, that when I visit this post a cookie is created via this code 'document.cookie="username="+username+";" ', the idea is that the extension returns the name, value and the javascript file that created that cookie. Please, let me know if I didn't explain well something